# Navigate between html files

Tags: javascript, html

I have two html file index.html  and test.html and I want to navigate from index to test when pressing a button.

I tried this but it is not working well .

```
function change_page(){
   console.log("change_page");
   $('body').load( "test.html");
} 


<input type="button" value="create page" onclick="change_page();"/>
```

If you know some better way, please tell me.

Comment: Are you sure you don´t use normal links (search engines, noJS user, etc.)? If not, what *nor working well* means?

Comment: If you want to use JavaScript: instead of $('body').load( "test.html"); try this: window.location.href = "test.html";

Comment: it is not loaded normally

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function change_page(){
  window.location.href = "test.html";
} 


<input type="button" value="create page" onclick="change_page()"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

Solutions:
1: Use an anchor tag to switch between the pages
2. If you really want to use Javascript you can do this

```
function change_page(){
   // similar behavior as an HTTP redirect
   window.location.replace("test.html");
   //or
   // similar behavior as clicking on a link
   window.location.href = "test.html";
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `anchor` tag `href` attribute to navigate another page like

```
 <a href="test.html">Test Page</a>
```

OR

You can try this

```
 <input type="button" value="create page" onclick="location.href='test.html'"/>
```

Comment: This is certainly the way to go.