# Send an image with js and html into form

Tags: javascript, php, html

I had a code that looks like this https://cloth.ardive.id/Tshirt/index.html

I want to send the canvas as an image to a form where user need to fill some addon information (name, category) and in this form image from page before is have been displayed and user doesnt need to upload an image anymore. So when they submit the form, submited form is contains their filled information data with the image

because i want to send the canvas that wasnt an image, so we need to generates the canvas into image, then send it to the form.

this is how my form code lookslike (I'm using wordpress and woocommerce, but this code is html). what I want to is navigating into the form page with image already uploaded to this field

```html
<script type="text/javascript">

            wpuf_conditional_items.push();

        </script>
        </li><li class="wpuf-el featured_image" data-label="Gambar">        <div class="wpuf-label">
            <label for="wpuf-featured_image">Gambar <span class="required">*</span></label>
        </div>
        
        <div class="wpuf-fields">
            <div id="wpuf-featured_image-upload-container" style="position: relative;"><div class="wpuf-file-warning"></div>
                <div class="wpuf-attachment-upload-filelist" data-type="file" data-required="yes">
                    <a id="wpuf-featured_image-pickfiles" data-form_id="4244" class="button file-selector  wpuf_featured_image_4244" href="https://cloth.ardive.id/buat-produk/#" style="position: relative; z-index: 1;">Select Image</a>

                    <ul class="wpuf-attachment-list thumbnails">
                                            </ul>
                </div>
            <div id="html5_1b67l1c6qtdqmec190711k33v46_container" class="moxie-shim moxie-shim-html5" style="position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 106px; height: 29px; overflow: hidden; z-index: 0;"><input id="html5_1b67l1c6qtdqmec190711k33v46" type="file" style="font-size: 999px; opacity: 0; position: absolute; top: 0px; left: 0px; width: 100%; height: 100%;" accept="image/jpeg,.jpg,.jpeg,image/gif,.gif,image/png,.png,image/bmp,.bmp"></div></div><!-- .container -->

            <span class="wpuf-help">Masukkan Gambar, gambar harus dengan resolusi tertinggi</span>

        </div> <!-- .wpuf-fields -->

        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery(function($) {
                new WPUF_Uploader('wpuf-featured_image-pickfiles', 'wpuf-featured_image-upload-container', 1, 'featured_image', 'jpg,jpeg,gif,png,bmp', 8000);
            });
        </script>
```

this is the code to save the image that have been already generated from the canvas to users desktop
the code is on canvas2image.js

```js
    // sends the generated file to the client
     var saveFile = function(strData) {
      document.location.href = strData;
     }
    
     var makeDataURI = function(strData, strMime) {
      return "data:" + strMime + ";base64," + strData;
     }
    
     // generates a <img> object containing the imagedata
     var makeImageObject = function(strSource) {
      var oImgElement = document.createElement("img");
      oImgElement.src = strSource;
      return oImgElement;
     }
    
     var scaleCanvas = function(oCanvas, iWidth, iHeight) {
      if (iWidth && iHeight) {
       var oSaveCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
       oSaveCanvas.width = iWidth;
       oSaveCanvas.height = iHeight;
       oSaveCanvas.style.width = iWidth+"px";
       oSaveCanvas.style.height = iHeight+"px";
    
       var oSaveCtx = oSaveCanvas.getContext("2d");
    
       oSaveCtx.drawImage(oCanvas, 0, 0, oCanvas.width, oCanvas.height, 0, 0, iWidth, iHeight);
       return oSaveCanvas;
      }
      return oCanvas;
     }
    
     return {
    
      saveAsPNG : function(oCanvas, bReturnImg, iWidth, iHeight) {
       if (!bHasDataURL) {
        return false;
       }
       var oScaledCanvas = scaleCanvas(oCanvas, iWidth, iHeight);
       var strData = oScaledCanvas.toDataURL("image/png");
       if (bReturnImg) {
        return makeImageObject(strData);
       } else {
        saveFile(strData.replace("image/png", strDownloadMime));
       }
       return true;
      }
```

this is another js to classed the function

```js
//export options
   $('.exportas').click(function(){
        // get type to export
        var to = $(this).data('type');
       // alert(to);
       // get our canvas
       var oCanvas = document.getElementById("mycanvas");  
    // support variable
    var bRes = false;
        if(to == 'png'){
            // export to png 
            bRes = Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(oCanvas);
        }
        if(to == 'jpg'){
            // maybe in some old browsers it works only on Firefox
            bRes = Canvas2Image.saveAsJPEG(oCanvas);
        }if(to == 'bmp'){
            Res = Canvas2Image.saveAsBMP(oCanvas);
        }
        // if browser doesn't support mimetype alert user
        if (!bRes) {
            alert("Sorry, this browser is not capable of saving " + strType + " files!");
            return false;
        }
```

and on index.html, its look like this

```html
<!-- export option (png, jpg, bmp) -->
                                <li>
                                    <div class="btn-group dropup">

                                      <a class="dropdown-toggle export btn" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
                                        Export
                                        <span class="caret"></span>
                                      </a>

                                      <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                        <li>
                                            <a href="#" class="exportas" data-type='png'>PNG</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="exportas" data-type='jpg'>JPG</a>
                                            <a href="#" class="exportas" data-type='bmp'>BMP</a>
                                        </li>
```

so what i wanna ask you is, how to make a code to send the image to form (form is on another pages) with details i have been mentioned above. thanks

Comment: How are you navigating from this page to the page with the form?

Comment: I don't know yet, have any idea? I will add my form code I forgot it

Comment: It depends on how you are navigating to your next page, but I recommend using https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage Session Storage to transfer the image data to the new page. `sessionStorage[keyName] = value` and get it with `var value = sessionStorage[keyName];` on the form page.

Comment: is theres a way to navigate it using html button called "submit" only? I'm new to this things

Comment: See this thread on navigating between pages with javascript http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24903148/navigate-between-html-files.

Also this article might be of help.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location

Comment: thank you very much. I will try it